# automatic refresh of GWT screen

Tags: gwt

I am working in GWT in the project.
I have a requirement in my project where I need an automatic refresh of my screen every 5 minutes.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: you want to auto-refresh the whole page or just a part of it?

Comment: i want to auto-refresh the whole page

Answer (score 3):

```
public class TimerExample implements EntryPoint, ClickListener {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    Button b = new Button("Click and wait 5 minutes");
    b.addClickListener(this);

    RootPanel.get().add(b);
  }

  public void onClick(Widget sender) {
    Timer t = new Timer() {
      public void run() {
        reloadAll();
      }
    };

    // Schedule the timer to run once in 5 minutes.
    t.schedule(5*1000*60);
  }

  private void reloadAll() {
    Window.Location.reload();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have 8-9 screens in my application and I want auto-refresh functionality in only one screen not all..Above example seems to refresh all the screens..let me know if i am wrong in my assumptions

Comment: The above code refreshes the whole content of the window. If you only want to refresh a certain part of your screen, replace the reloadAll() function with code that recreates that part's view (with some Ajax calls to re-fetch data from server if needed).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Activies and Places](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces) framework from GWT, you could use the activity-mapper with the 'goTo(samePlace)' method to handle your usecase easily. It's part of the MVP design/pattern.

Comment: Yes, I am using Activities and Places in my apps. goTo will navigate to other screen. i want auto refresh of a page..

Comment: Anand, activities/places or mvp4g history is the most appropriate way. I am sure you could schedule an invocation event.

Comment: @BlessedGeek is right. It would be better to have his solution, e.g. in your presenter as if it's only related to the view of that presenter. Sometimes, I use places/activies to refresh the state of a view. But it has to be alright with the flow of my pages. (I might be doing something awefully wrong, I hope not!)

Answer (score 0):

Refresh every 300 seconds (5 minutes):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

Place this meta tag under the head element of your gwt html hosting page.

If you use a JSP rather than a HTML file as the GWT hosting file, you could do this

```
<%
   String refreshInterval = request.getParameter("refreshInterval");
%>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=refreshInterval%>">
</head>
```

Comment: but putting the above meta tag in gwt hosting page will refresh the whole application every 5 minutes..I want to refresh a particular page in my application