# GWT auto refresh

Tags: gwt

I am working in GWT project. As per the requirement, i have to provide auto-refresh to one of my screen. 
My senior told me to use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">` in that screen page.

But as GWT code is written in java only, so i wonder how can I use it in java file.

Can somebody help?

Comment: You already have asked it at automatic refresh of GWT screen -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12092874/432903

Comment: in that it is written "Place this meta tag under the head element of your gwt html hosting page." but doing so, will it not auto-refresh all the screens? I want auto-refresh on only one screen not all screens

Comment: Do you really need to reload the whole page? Or do you only need to refresh a table or chart with new requested data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you are managing history and if you are not using places. You can use the location reload event inside a timer.

If you are using places, you can use your place controller to re navigate to the same place every 30 seconds

```
Timer t = new Timer() {
    public void run() {
        Window.Location.reload();
    }
};
t.scheduleRepeating(30000);
```

Comment: The edit is incorrect, if you are going to schedule repeating then the inner schedule needs to be removed. This will cause adverse affects.