# GWT Auto Refresh Code Jumps To Home Page

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

We want to auto refresh a page that is built using GWT 2. We used a lot of solutions to do it:

[GWT auto refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195207/gwt-auto-refresh)

[automatic refresh of GWT screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092705/automatic-refresh-of-gwt-screen/12092874#12092874)

But neither of them worked properly. The problem is a bit complicated:

The auto refresh works in the home page/tab called "Kazalar":

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/103580364/temp/000766.jpg

But if the user is in another tab then after auto refresh the browser jumps to home page/tab:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/103580364/temp/000767.jpg

In the above [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092705/automatic-refresh-of-gwt-screen/12092874#12092874), the answerer [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092705/automatic-refresh-of-gwt-screen/12092874#comment16159270_12092874) that we should replace the reloadAll() function with code that recreates that part's view (with some Ajax calls to re-fetch data from server if needed). We couldn't test this part because we don't know how to write the code that recreates a specific part's view. Could someone please give an example on how to do it?

```
public class TimerExample implements EntryPoint, ClickListener {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    Button b = new Button("Click and wait 5 minutes");
    b.addClickListener(this);

    RootPanel.get().add(b);
  }

  public void onClick(Widget sender) {
    Timer t = new Timer
      public void run() {
        reloadAll();
      }
    };

    // Schedule the timer to run once in 5 minutes.
    t.schedule(5*1000*60);
  }

  private void reloadAll() {
    Window.Location.reload();
  }
}
```

Comment: When the "Kazalar" place is revealed you start this timer, when `Timer.run()` is called, you call the same method you used to fill the data on the first time you loaded that tab.

Comment: I would suggest not to make a Location.reload(). Just reload your displayed data in your timer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a timer is fine.

Assuming you know about [GWT activities and places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).
The harsh way would be to reload the full module using

```
Window.Location.replace("url#kalazar:");
```

You already mentionned it; but a really nicer way (assuming you are implemeting the MVP pattern) would be to create a refresh method on the presenter of the Kalazar view. This way you won't need to reload the page.

```
  private void reloadAll() {
    myKalazarPresenter.refresh();
  }

  private void myKalazarPresenter() {
    myKalazarView.clear();
    myKalazerView.reInit(kalazarInitializationData);
  }
```

Since you say you can't reInit the view, maybe you could just try to delete and recreate it ?