# GWT How to automatically refresh page every 5 minutes without clicking button for it?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am trying to design the function in my GWT application to automatically refresh one of the pages every 5 minutes without clicking button before reloading.Most of the examples I have found in stackoverflow for this function are triggered after user click button or link. Like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092705/automatic-refresh-of-gwt-screen)

I just want page to be automatically refreshed every 5 minutes.

Comment: Just use `onLoad` rather than `onClick` *exactly* as the duplicate example question!

Comment: possible duplicate of [automatic refresh of GWT screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092705/automatic-refresh-of-gwt-screen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put this code anywhere you need it:

```
Timer timer = new Timer() {
    public void run() {
        Window.Location.reload();
    }
};
timer.schedule(5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Remember to cancel this timer at some point - otherwise it will keep refreshing forever, even if a user simply left your app open in a some tab and forgot about it.